# Include deletion of an answer in activity log?

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

I've submitted an answer to a question. I've deleted that answer because in the same moment another user submitted a better answer, that turned mine somewhat redundant.

Later, looking for that very post, I tried to find an entry in the activity log. I expected to find an entry *answered* followed by an entry *deleted* there.

Why isn't this the case? I think it would be nice to be this way.

Comment: The edit history for your post shows that it was answered, then deleted. The question's history only shows revisions of the question, not answers

Comment: @AvadaKedavra The OP already knew he deleted an answer from that question.